# How to select id's of multiple products using VQL?

Tags: sql, node.js, vql

I currently have the following query to select the id of a single product, like so:

```
client.post(`https://merck-nextgen.veevavault.com/api/v18.3/query?q=SELECT id FROM product__v WHERE name__v = '${VOLT_CREDENTIALS.get('cred').productName }'` , args , function( data , res) {
            //console.log( 'PRODUCT ID IS ' + data.data[0].id);
            productID = data.data[0].id;
            resolve("Product ID retrieved ...");
});
```

But what if I have multiple products, i.e. maybe more than one, how do I go ahead and select the id's of multiple products using the same query as above?

I am using nodejs and [VQL](https://developer.veevavault.com/vql/#using-date-amp-datetime-values).

Right now the value of `VOLT_CREDENTIALS.get('cred').productName` is just "demoproduct". So how do I go about selecting the id's of multiple products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the filtering condition:

```
WHERE name__v = '${VOLT_CREDENTIALS.get('cred').productName }'
```

you can use:

```
WHERE name__v = '${VOLT_CREDENTIALS.get('cred').productName1 }'
   OR name__v = '${VOLT_CREDENTIALS.get('cred').productName2 }'
   OR name__v = '${VOLT_CREDENTIALS.get('cred').productName3 }'
```

You get the idea.

Comment: thanks for the answer , it can't be an `or` though  , if its 2 products , i need the id's of both , if 3 products , i need the id of all 3 :)